# MongoDB slow log (profiler) shows many many "killcursors" action when heavy load comes, why? and what killcursors do?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, database, nosql

```
2015 - 05 - 13 T21: 55: 10.876 + 0800 I QUERY[conn8674] killcursors keyUpdates: 0 writeConflicts: 0 numYields: 0 locks: {
    Global: {
    acquireCount: {
        r: 1
    }
    },
    MMAPV1Journal: {
    acquireCount: {
        r: 1
    }
    },
    Database: {
    acquireCount: {
        r: 1
    }
    },
    Collection: {
    acquireCount: {
        R: 1
    }
    }
}
1641 ms 2015 - 05 - 13 T21: 55: 10.877 + 0800 I QUERY[conn8618] killcursors keyUpdates: 0 writeConflicts: 0 numYields: 0 locks: {
    Global: {
    acquireCount: {
        r: 1
    }
    },
    MMAPV1Journal: {
    acquireCount: {
        r: 1
    }
    },
    Database: {
    acquireCount: {
        r: 1
    }
    },
    Collection: {
    acquireCount: {
        R: 1
    }
    }
}
1648 ms
```

Comment: Are you using cursors to retrieve data from MongoDB and iterating on that data?

Comment: @NachiketKate maybe or must be, most time it's ok, when qps>300 or higher, the slow log outputs killcursors with 1000+ms.

Comment: Error is saying same thing. Do you really need that? If not change it to more optimal way and then check again.